# SQL behaviour when using string literal vs using date literal

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

Suppose I have this two queries:

1. `SELECT * FROM payments WHERE created < DATE '1967-01-01'`
2. `SELECT * FROM payments WHERE created < '1967-01-01'`

And `created` field is a date field.

I would like to know if in query 2) is comparing two dates like in 1) and is not comparing two strings lexicographically.

Thanks!

Comment: I have deleted my answer because I wrongly thought that the question was about SQL Server. The MySQL rules are very different. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: You should probably ensure you use a `CAST` or `CONVERT` to make sure that the comparison is done in the way you want.

Comment: Implicit cast as date, but I'd still recommend using a proper date literal, i.e. query 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql treats both formats as dates, not as strings.

As mysql manual on [date and time literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html) say:

> Standard SQL requires temporal literals to be specified using a type
> keyword and a string. The space between the keyword and string is
> optional.
>
> DATE 'str' TIME 'str' TIMESTAMP 'str' MySQL recognizes but, unlike
> standard SQL, does not require the type keyword. Applications that are
> to be standard-compliant should include the type keyword for temporal
> literals.

> ...
>
> MySQL recognizes DATE values in these formats:
>
> As a string in either 'YYYY-MM-DD' or 'YY-MM-DD' format.